# Xtext cross reference for language with enum types

Tags: xtext

I'm have a simple language with something like enum's. How can I get working solution for cross-referenced EnumEntry. Also it will be good to filter EnumEntry by EnumEntity...

MyDsl.xtext

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with    
org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    entity_node = Entity | EnumEntity;

Entity:
    type = ('my_entity') ':' name = ID '{'  
    (parts += EntityPart)*
    '}';

EnumEntity:
    type = ('my_enum') ':' name = ID '{'
    //entry = EnumEntry (',' entrys+= EnumEntry)* Fixed after Christian comment
    entrys+= EnumEntry (',' entrys+= EnumEntry)*
    '}';

EnumEntry:
    name = ID;

EnumUsage:
    /* What should I do here? */
    enumEntity = [EnumEntity]'.'entry = [EnumEntry];

EntityPart:
    EnumUsage ';';
```

my_enum_entity.mydsl

```
my_enum:my_enum_entity
{
    my_enum_entry_1,
    my_enum_entry_2,
    my_enum_entry_3
}
```

my_pretty_entity.mydsl

```
my_entity:my_pretty_entity
{
    my_enum_entity.my_enum_entry_2;                                                 
}
```

[image: Some error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not customize the scopeprovider or did you simply missed to post the code?

id expect something like

```
class MyDslScopeProvider extends AbstractMyDslScopeProvider {

    override getScope(EObject context, EReference reference) {
        if (reference == MyDslPackage.Literals.ENUM_USAGE__ENUM_ENTRY) {
            if (context instanceof EnumUsage) {
                return Scopes.scopeFor(context.enumEntity.entrys)
            }
        }
        super.getScope(context, reference)
    }

}
```

if you dont want to adapt scoping adapt the grammar like

```
EnumUsage: entry = [EnumEntry|FQN];
FQN: ID ("." ID)*;
```

Comment: Nop, i didn't change scopeprovider =) Can you provide an example how it can be dove by overriding it? =)

Comment: Thank you, but maybe it's must be MyDslPackage.Literals.ENUM_USAGE__ENUM_ENTRY ?

Comment: Also Scopes.scopeFor(context.enumEntity.entrys) will lose first entry, so it seems that there must be Scopes.scopeFor(context.enumEntity.eContents)

Comment: Well this is caused by your very very strange grammar I overlooked in the first place. It should be entrys += ... for the first element as well

Comment: Yes but the pattern is list+=Element ("," list += Element)*

Comment: One more question... Why it may not work on a biggest project, with maybe 400+ files with myDsl? Same eclipse build, but different workspace, plugin work just fine, show coloring and ect, but lost cross references...

Comment: Without any hints on how to reproduce I have no idea. Sure the project has xtext nature and build automatically is on?

Comment: Ok, my bad =) Project settings - Builders - Xtext Project Builder has been disabled. Thank you for you'r help! ^_^ Seems like now I need to find something simmilar in Intellij Idea project...

Comment: And in Intellij Idea module must have a Facet with you'r dsl and cross-references work only in folders marked as source...